# Pandas groupby aggregation with variable time windows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (`df`) that is like the one below:

```
month-year    name    a    b    c  start_date    end_date
2018-01       X       2    1    4  2018-01-01    2018-01-31
2018-01       Y       1    0    5  2018-01-01    2018-02-31
2018-01       X       1    6    3  2018-01-01    2018-01-31
2018-01       Y       4    10   7  2018-01-01    2018-02-31
2018-02       X       13   4    2  2018-02-01    2018-02-31 
2018-02       Y       22   13   9  2018-01-01    2018-02-31
2018-02       X       3    7    4  2018-02-01    2018-02-31 
2018-02       Y       2    15   0  2018-01-01    2018-02-31
```

I want to `groupby` `month-year` and `name` to get the sum of column `a`, average of column `b`, and std of column `c`. However, I want the sum, average, and std to be a rolling/cumulative number. On top of that, I want the rolling/cumulative number to be the rolling/cumulative number within the `start_date` and `end_date`.

In other words, what can i do to get an output like this?

```
month-year    name    a    b    c
2018-01       X       3    3.5  0.71
              Y       5    5    1.41
2018-02       X       16   5.5  1.4
              Y       29   9.5  3.86
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby().agg()

```
df.groupby(['month-year', 'name']).agg({'a':'sum', 'b':'mean', 'c':'std'})


                        a    b    c
month-year  name            
2018-01-01   X         3    3.5   0.707107
             Y         5    5.0   1.414214
2018-02-01   X         16   5.5   1.414214
             Y         24   14.0  6.363961
```

Comment: I believe that doesn't work for some parts. It works for X, whose start_date and end_date are always the beginning and end of the month. However, for Y, whose start_date and end_date have a delta of two months, I want the entries in 2018-02 to show a cumulative sum for 2018-01 and 2018-02.